# Use previous Array Value if current value is Empty - Reading from CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv, replace

I have a CSV file with content similar to the following:

```
"Red",Red Coat
"",Red Dog
"",Red Car
"Blue",Blue Stuff
"Green",Green Stuff
"",Green Grass
```

I can read this and am output via PHP.

```
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
$row=0;
$csv_row = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$csv_row = $data;

      $previous=$csv_row[0]
      $colour=$csv_row[0]
      if $colouris null then $colour=$previous;
      echo $colour." ".$csv_row[1]."<BR>";

}
fclose($handle);
}
```

And this will show me the Output with blanks for missing items.

Im not a Developer so forgive the question and ugly logic below. I want to use the existing value of $colour for the next $colour if its blank.

So something like:

```
      $previous=$csv_row[0]
      $colour=$csv_row[0]
      if $colour is null then $colour=$previous;
```

So for my CSV would show me:

```
 Red Red Coat
 Red Red Dog ( previously Colour was empty)
 Red Red Car ( previously Colour was empty)
 Blue Blue Stuff
 Green Green Stuff
 Green Green Grass ( previously Colour was empty)
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think it's null, I think it's value is empty,  try if $colour == ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

```
if $colour is null then $colour=$previous;
```

To this :

```
if (!$colour)
{
    $colour = $previous;
}
```

So if $colour is null, or empty, $colour will take the value from $previous.

Also, I think you may want to change this :

```
$previous=$csv_row[0];
$colour=$csv_row[0];
```

To this :

```
$previous=$csv_row[0];
$colour=$csv_row[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change a small amount in your code. The $previous variable is not necessary.

This works -

```
if (($handle = fopen("a.php", "r")) !== FALSE) {
$row=0;
$csv_row = array();

$color = "";
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $csv_row = $data;
    //Don't update $color if no color available.
    if($csv_row[0] != null){
        $color = $csv_row[0];
    }
    echo $color." ".$csv_row[1]."<BR>";
}
fclose($handle);
}

/*
OUTPUT:
Red Red Coat
Red Red Dog
Red Red Car
Blue Blue Stuff
Green Green Stuff
Green Green Grass
*/
```

Comment: Thank you both , I ended up using this as it was a direct copy paste for me. Much appreciated.